# How to create a vector feature drop target?

Tags: openlayers-2

I would like to create, inside an openLayers map, a drop target for my features.

The user should be able to drag a vector feature, drop on the target so that some further action can be triggered (in the specific it would be moving the feature to a new map object.)

I have tried to do this by adding a `OpenLayers.Control.Button`to the map, my problem now is that I cannot sort out the z-index issue: when dragged on the target, the feature disappears **behind** the button.

Is there any way i can set up properly the CSS of the button so that it stays *above the map tiles but below the features*?

I have noticed that the map is on `z-index` 749, the vector features in a nested `div` with `z-index` 330 - I have tried to set the button to `z-index` 749 too but the feature still moves below.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

With OpenLayers you have the option to set one layer as the BaseLayer, then the other ones are overlays.

**The order of definition is used as "overlay Z order"**. 
Example:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map(...);
    map.addLayer( ... below, low Z position ... );
    map.addLayer( ... above, high Z position ... );
    // now you have (map.layers.length==2)
```

For any other "external object" that need to go "above", I use CSS with "z-index:99999999".
Example: the z-index of the automplete-text or a select (combo-box) at the top of the map.

I do not recommend, for reasons of user-interface, the inclusion of HTML fragments inside the map (!), 
except total ones, like a [modal dialog](http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/integration/jqui-dialog.html),  or when the HTMLfrag 
himself is part of a layer. Typical example of this last one is a the `contentHTML`
parameter of the a [OpenLayers.Popup](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html) constructor. 
There you can interact with things like <button> tags.

## Z-Index access

If you set the layers with map.addLayer, the pointer is at the `map.layers` array, 
that is, you need know *a priori* the index `i` of your layer `map.layers[i]`. 
Or you can set a var,

```
var mayLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer... ;
...  map.addLayer(mayLayer); ...
```

For any layer you can use the [getZIndex method](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html),
to check the exact z-index, and associate this z-index to the HTML fragment.

```
   var myZval = mayLayer.getZIndex(); // or map.layers[x].getZIndex();
```

Another way to check OpenLayers zindex managing is the Z_INDEX_BASE variable: it is a (not documented) object containing the following propperties:

```
{ BaseLayer: 100
,Overlay: 325
,Feature: 725
,Popup: 750
,Control: 1000 
}
```

So, you can use a relative z-index. For example,

```
myMakerLayer0.setZIndex(map.Z_INDEX_BASE['Popup'] - 2);
```

Of course, the best way to positionate your HTML fragment is [with DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_zindex.asp)
 — I prefer [jQuery to access DOM with OpenLayers](http://linfiniti.com/2010/02/fancy-map-toolbar-for-openlayers/).

```
 HTMLObject.style.zIndex=myZval;
```

PS: I not use it, but see also [OpenLayers.ElementsIndexer](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Renderer/Elements-js.html).

## Interface control

See [Styling](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html), etc.

In [this example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/stylemap.html) the on-mouse-over changes the z-index of each vector feature in the same layer.

Comment: I know about z-indexing, but my drop target should stay in a fixed position in the map viewport like a button, so I cannot see how I could implement this with a vector layer...

Comment: and the vector feature should in the end hover it - so the z-order should be base map<target button<feature, not the standard map<feature<target

Comment: ... Hum... Ok, I edited, adding "Z-Index access" section and more details.

Comment: (+1) though, you should not use z-index:9999999999... it's over the top man, don't get crazy :). 2147483647 is the largest value of a signed integer on a 32 bit OS.

Comment: ops, (ok edited), sorry, 8 or 9 '9s' are more than sufficient :)