# Drawing a rectangle that will always be on certain area of map

Tags: openlayers-2

Using OpenLayers is it possible to draw a rectange that will always be on one portion of map without regards to zooming and panning of map?

Comment: You could use a div & position it using CSS. That might be the easiest option.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I want it to be redrawn like any layer.

Comment: Why do you want it to redraw, if it is not going to change its position on the screen? and you can always toggle its visibility when the map pans or zooms to give a similar effect.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe IF it's layer itself then I will be able to print it and redraw it when it's value change using timer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is like the car window in a race game?
Here a red box

```
 <div style="z-index:99999999; position:fixed; 
             top:300px; right:300px; width:80px; height:80px;
             border-color:red; border-style:solid; border-width:2px;
 ">&nbsp;</div>
```

Change `position` to `relative` (a `div` into the map's div) if you need it scrolling with the page, p. ex.

```
 position:relative; z-index:99999999; top:30px; right:-40px;
```

See also [z-index at map layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33558/7505), [CSS positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp), and [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

Comment: How can I make this div movable with mouse??

Comment: It is "like a STATIONARY window" :-)   Well, your question is about drawing a rectangle "*that will always be on certain area*", so it is stationary.     For "animation"   (you need to post a new question!) the `div` must have a ID and you can use jQuery to control it.  PS: about playing this question-and-answer-game, my answer is acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the [Vector layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html), and set its [isFixed](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.isFixed) property to true.
 This way the vector layer will not move around when the map is dragged, but is printed and redrawn with the map.

Comment: I will try this .. it seems good

Comment: "Note that setting this to true will move the layer to the bottom of the layer stack" so if I have opaque layer on top then it will block eveything :(. I Need it on the top.